# Dúvida sobre preenchimento de arrays e funções dentro de arrays

Tags: java, array

> `insira o código aquiArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
>   for(contador=0;contador<x;contador++){
>   Player p1 = new Player();
>   p1.setId(contador);
>   p1.setSaldo(valorinteger = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
>   players.add(p1);
>   }`

**1-** Preciso criar X players nesse array, e cada 1 terá um saldo diferente.
como posso fazer isso visto que assim não está funcionando.

**2-** tenho o array players, e preciso chamar uma função por exemplo, getsaldo(); de/cada um dos players que está no array. Como posso fazer isso?
Desde já agradeço a ajuda, estou com um grande trabalho pra entregar e sei muito pouco de java.

Comment: Código correto.
for(contador=0; contador<valorfixo;contador++){
    Player p1 = new Player();
    p1.setId(contador);
    p1.setSaldo(valorinteger = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));
    players.add(p1);
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu objeto Player é uma classe, você já esta setando um método set que atribui o valor do saldo do player em cada instância que você esta criando no for, para você pegar o valor de cada player dentro do array players, basta percorrer o ArrayList com um for e usar o método getSaldo() de cada Player, mas pra isso você terá que criar esse método dentro da classe Player.
Exemplo:

```
ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
    int valorfixo = 5;
    for (int contador = 0; contador < valorfixo; contador++) {
        Player p1 = new Player();
        p1.setId(contador);
        int valorRandomico = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        p1.setSaldo(valorRandomico);
        players.add(p1);
    }

    for (Player player : players) {
        System.out.println(player.getSaldo());
    }
```

Classe Player:

```
public class Player {
private int id;
private int saldo;
public Player(){

}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getSaldo() {
    return saldo;
}
public void setSaldo(int saldo) {
    this.saldo = saldo;
}}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porém fiquei com algumas dúvidas. O que esse for (Player player : players) { está fazendo? Ele esta correndo o array player? Se for, tem como eu manualmente escolher um player no meio do array pra pegar o saldo ex: player[2].getsaldo?
Outra dúvida, sabe como posso estanciar vários objetos player dentro do array player?

Comment: Sim, o for que esta sendo usado é conhecido como for each, ele percorre toda uma lista ou array, o player é o objeto que esta sendo listado no momento. Para você pegar um objeto específico em um ArrayList você tem que usar o método players.get(2).getSaldo();
Para mais informações dos métodos do ArrayList veja a documentação dele no link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Sobre sua última dúvida, você já esta colocando várias instâncias do objeto Player no array players na linha players.add(p1); .
Nesse seu for você cria uma instância do player: Player p1 = new Player();

Comment: Entendi sobre o for each e get, muto clara sua explicação.
A última duvida é sobre o for do array. Se ele está correto. Porque estou criando uma instancia de player que é p1 e vou preencher todas as posicoes do arraylist com ela.
Feito isso, posso ir alterando os valores de cada p1 dentro do array com as funções da classe.
Tipo colocar o nome "A" no p1 que fica na posição 0, nome "b" no p1 que fica na posição 1, etc.
Desculpe se não estou sendo muito claro, realmente entendo muito pouco de java.

Comment: Sim, sua variável p1 é instanciada a cada iteração do loop for, sendo assim você conseguirá que cada objeto p1 que você adicionou no seu array é independente do outro.